# c# Draw a graph with chart winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, charts

I try to draw a graph (chartType = Line) that I retrieve from a BDD, on the ordinate I own places and on the abscissa of the hours.
I want to draw a route (places) according to the time (time of passage to the place) to compare with other routes.

But I can't put string on the axe Y.

```
Const string DB_CONN_STR = "SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=test7100; UID=root; PASSWORD=";

        MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(DB_CONN_STR);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string sqlCmd = "SELECT  `PR4`, `DHT`, `DHR` FROM `table 4` WHERE 1";
            // PR4= place et DHT= time
            MySqlDataAdapter adr = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd, cn);
            adr.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            adr.Fill(dt);



        string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        string[] y = new string[dt.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            y[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            x[i] = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            grapheSillon.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x[i], y[i]);
        }
```

Comment: What type in db have PR4 and DHT ? And what you mean "can't put string on the axe Y." ? Any exception are you take?

Comment: __Neither__ x- nor y-values should be strings!! If you add the x-values as strings they are all set to 0, ie __lost__ except for the labels. At least the DataPoints are all added side by side. But if you add the y-values as strings no meaningful chart can be created at all unless the y-values can convert to numbers..! - Best sghow what you have and what you want!

Comment: PR4 has type string and DHT time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to add string on Y axis

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count ; i++)
            {

                chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(i, i + 1, label[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for your answer.
I apologize, I have misspoke.

I understood that I could not put strings on the abscissa or ordinate. The solution I put in Y axis :integers and in X axis :hours in the format: "hh: mm: ss".
But I still have two problems to solve.

The first: I have to display two curves that have the same coordinates in Y but in X it is different (different times)
When I display my two curves, it is superimposed, I get only one curve it does not make the difference of the abscissa coordinates.

The second problem is how do I put labels in the Y axis, ie instead of displaying int, I display strings?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7o5J.png)

```
 Const string DB_CONN_STR = "SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=test7100; UID=root; PASSWORD=";

        MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(DB_CONN_STR);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string sqlCmd = "SELECT  `PR4`, `DHT`, `DHR` FROM `table 4` WHERE 1";
            // PR4= place et DHT= time
            MySqlDataAdapter adr = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd, cn);
            adr.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            adr.Fill(dt);



        string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        string[] y = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        string[] z= new string[dt.Rows.Count]


        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            y[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(); // place
            x[i] = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString(); //  theoretical hour format : "hh:mm:ss"
            z[i] = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString(); //  real hour format : "hh:mm:ss" 

        }
int j= dt.rows.count //j=33
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            grapheSillon.Series["théorique"].Points.AddXY(x[i], j);
            grapheSillon.Series["réel"].Points.AddXY(z[i], j);
            j=j-1
        }
```